# Как не выводить текст на новую строку?

Tags: python

Собственно сама проблема: по идее код должен выводить текст без переноса на новую строку, для чего я прописал end ='\n' в конце строки, но он не работает.
фото с консоли прикрепил ниже:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/99M0D.png

````
while True:
    spoof("192.168.0.200", "192.168.0.1")
    spoof("192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.200")
    sent_packets_count = sent_packets_count + 2
    print("[+] Packets sent: " + str(sent_packets_count),end='\n')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(2)
 

Также пробовал такую вариацию:
    ```print("[+] Packets sent: " + str(sent_packets_count))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

end='\n' это и есть перенос на новую строку, исспользуемый по умолчанию
end='X' здесь X будет разделителем строк

```
print('a','b',end='X')
#a bX
```

end='\r' возврат каретки то есть возврат в начало строки вывода

```
print('123456',end='\r')
print('AAA')
#AAA456
```

Comment: проблема была в том, что я запускал питон 3ей версии, а такой метод работает для 2.7 и ниже, ganz'у спасибо за объяснение, строка теперь выглядит так:
    ```print("\r[+] Packets sent: " + str(sent_packets_count),end="")```